# How can I make a UIButton enable as a function when I touch outside the button and drag over the button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any event for this dragging from outside of button in to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of events available to control objects within the [UIControl class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The control event your looking for is:

**UIControlEventTouchDragInside**

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function

```
-(IBAction)enableAction:(id)sender
{
     myButton.Enabled = YES;

}
```

and link it to  TouchDragInside or TouchDragOutside  event in interface builder

Comment: I cant get that, please explain clearly.

Comment: To Radu, If I had a label and a button If i touch outside the button and swiped over the button then an event should be fired to display "hello"  in the label field. tell me how can I do it?